# dotnet rosalyn compiler error MSB6006: "csc.exe" exited with code 8

Tags: .net, msbuild, .net-core

I am facing this error in amazon linux while trying to run dotnet build command.
I am trying to use sonarqube .net core scanner and as part of that running dotnet build command.

```
sudo dotnet build --no-restore --verbosity d --no-dependencies
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.3.409.57025 for .NET Core
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Build started 11/27/18 11:42:22 AM.
1>Project "/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/multibranch_pipeline_master-VFQZN2R7JTITZDJOVBS6UDCECP2XJL7TD55373F64OTKZXE63T4Q/source/WebServer/UP/DotNetAPI/DotNetAPI.csproj" on node 1 (Build target(s)).
1>Building with tools version "15.0".
Project file contains ToolsVersion="". This toolset may be unknown or missing, in which case you may be able to resolve this by installing the appropriate version of MSBuild, or the build may have been forced to a particular ToolsVersion for policy reasons. Treating the project as if it had ToolsVersion="15.0". For more information, please see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=293424.
1>Target "Build" in project "/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/multibranch_pipeline_master-VFQZN2R7JTITZDJOVBS6UDCECP2XJL7TD55373F64OTKZXE63T4Q/source/WebServer/UP/DotNetAPI/DotNetAPI.csproj" (entry point):
Using "Csc" task from assembly "/opt/dotnet/sdk/2.0.0/Roslyn/Microsoft.Build.Tasks.CodeAnalysis.dll".
Task "Csc"
/opt/dotnet/sdk/2.0.0/Roslyn/csc.exe /out:/DotNetAPI.dll /target:library ReliabilityMain.cs
1>/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/multibranch_pipeline_master-VFQZN2R7JTITZDJOVBS6UDCECP2XJL7TD55373F64OTKZXE63T4Q/source/WebServer/UP/DotNetAPI/DotNetAPI.csproj(10,5): error MSB6006: "csc.exe" exited with code 8.
Done executing task "Csc" -- FAILED.
1>Done building target "Build" in project "DotNetAPI.csproj" -- FAILED.
```

My .csproj file is as shown below

````
```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
   <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
 </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>  
    <Compile Include="ReliabilityMain.cs"/>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Net.Compilers" Version="2.4.0" />
  </ItemGroup>  
  <Target Name="Build">  
    <Csc Sources="@(Compile)"
    TargetType="library"
     OutputAssembly="$(builtdir)\$(MSBuildProjectName).dll"
    />    
  </Target>  
</Project>  
```
````

Comment: Did you intentionally create the csproj that way instead of using a `dotnet new` template?

Comment: yes i am trying to provide a csproj file and control build thru it.

Comment: But the csproj file isn't what a typical csproj file would look like, since you're likely missing a lot of inputs to the csc task. can you build using a higher log leve? (e.g. `-flp:verbosity=diag` to generate a msbuild.log)

Comment: I was able to resolve it by changing the csproj file contents. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I've faced this problem when I tried to build my project from VS Code instead of Visual Studio (macOS environment).
After some unsuccessful research, I just removed the reference to `Microsoft.Net.Compilers`

After removing it, I could be able to run, build and debug both from VS Code and Visual Studio for MAC.

I hope it helps.